# How to tune ilike query involving multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE "account_id" = 765 AND first_name ilike 'rahul%';
```

The query is currently taking 100ms plus, I have individually indexed account_id and first_name. First name is using gist index.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on patients  (cost=960.12..29301.39 rows=61 width=117) (actual time=8.399..100.206 rows=11 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (account_id = 765)
  Filter: ((first_name)::text ~~* 'rahul'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 28978
  Heap Blocks: exact=8948
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_patients_on_account_id  (cost=0.00..960.11 rows=31424 width=0) (actual time=4.569..4.569 rows=29003 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (account_id = 765)
Planning Time: 0.774 ms
Execution Time: 100.251 ms
```

I feel I need a multi column index, not sure about how to go about creating it.

Comment: Will that improve performance ?

Comment: I don't understand why my question is downvoted.

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/5p8a

Comment: Sorry it's a pattern match I am looking for.. I will update my question.

Comment: I have a multi-tenant application. So data is spread across the table.

Comment: Is it possible to add multi-column index here?

Comment: You have updated your query text, but your explain still shows it processing the old form.

Comment: There are many ways to specify a GiST index.  Please show us the CREATE statement for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rewrite your query using `LIKE` and `lower` and if the wildcard is always at the end of the pattern, then the optimal index would probably be:

```
create index on patients (account_id, lower(first_name) text_pattern_ops)
```

With a query as:

```
SELECT * FROM patients
  WHERE "account_id" = 765 AND lower(first_name) like lower('rahul%');
```

The first `lower` needs to be there to match the index.  The 2nd `lower` is optional, it can be removed if you know the client will always provide an already lower-case string.

Comment: I guess "ilike" is not what I needed. I will try to implement this solution. Thanks.